# macOS cannot find nvm, and npm and global installed packages

Tags: bash, macos, symlink, macos-catalina, nvm

I did install nvm regarding the [documentation](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating), on a macOS Catalina 10.15.3. Then installed the latest LTS node, `nvm install 12.16.1` and globally installed yarn.

everything was working well, the `node -v` and `npm -v` and `which node` were showing what they should.

I did create a react-native app and the metro bundler had a problem finding node. The solution was to [make a symlink](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22918#issuecomment-455960705)(`ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node`).

Since then, `nvm`, `npm`, `yarn` commands are not found by the terminal (zsh).

I could not find a proper way to install node via nvm where all programs and shells can have access to it. Without needing symbolic links or so.

This is the script added to `.bash_profile` after installing nvm

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think that you are not modifying the **.zshrc**(analog of **.bash_profile**).

I recommend this post to guide you [How to Configure your macOs Terminal with Zsh like a Pro](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-configure-your-macos-terminal-with-zsh-like-a-pro-c0ab3f3c1156/)

Comment: Well, though none of the topics in that article, address my problem, thanks for the link